# error: unable to set the formulaarray property of the range class

Tags: excel

I have formular array in one work book which I copy to another workbook during record of macro. After recording it stop working with error: unable to set the formulaarray property of the range class

My code

```
Windows("TT Analysis 5th Exercise.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("HW CA").Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=IF(AND(MIN(IF(RC[-1]=R2C2:R14829C2,R2C12:R14829C12))=100,RC[-2]=100),""No Site Outage"",IF(AND(MIN(IF(RC[-1]=R2C2:R14829C2,R2C12:R14829C12))<100,RC[-2]=100),""No Cells Outage"",IF(MAX(IF(RC[-1]=R2C2:R14829C2,R2C12:R14829C12))-RC[-2]>5,""Worst cell"",""Site Outage"")))"
    Windows("RAN Report Template.xlsx").Activate
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(AND(MIN(IF(RC[-4]=R2C2:R14829C2,R2C12:R14829C12))=100,RC[-5]=100),""No Site Outage"",IF(AND(MIN(IF(RC[-4]=R2C2:R14829C2,R2C12:R14829C12))<100,RC[-5]=100),""No Cells Outage"",IF(MAX(IF(RC[-4]=R2C2:R14829C2,R2C12:R14829C12))-RC[-5]>5,""Worst cell"",""Site Outage"")))"
    Columns("I:J").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is due to a formula array syntax error.  If you were to manually create a formula array within a cell (without VBA), you would have to hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, for excel to properly treat that formula as an array.  The reason why I bring this up, is because I suggest you test this first.  If your formula works, then at that point you just need to make sure you have your VBA code add the proper brackets surrounding the formula, so it acts as an array.
I hope this makes sense.  See this [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d) for additional info